# python List typecasting and setting values

Tags: python, list, casting

I was trying this out

```
>>> x = [[1, 2, 3], 10.5]
>>> z = list(x)
>>> z[1] = 10.6
>>> z
[[1, 2, 3], 10.6]
>>> x
[[1, 2, 3], 10.5]
>>> z[0][2] = 5
>>> z
[[1, 2, 5], 10.6]
>>> x
[[1, 2, 5], 10.5]
```

Why the change is being reflected in x[0][2] ? and similarly not in x[1]???

Answer (score 2):

The `list(x)` created a new top-level list thus changing its top-level values - like `10.5` - won't propagate to `x`. On the other hand, the inner list is a reference thus changes to it are shared amongst all containers containing it because they all contain the very same object. If you would like a separate copy of `x`, use [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).